# List View web part Column header Filter does not fetch list values updated via SharePoint Designer xsl calculation

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have a List View WebPart with a column 'due date 'and 'alert'  .

In SharePoint designer I have modifed the xsl and uses a calculation to check if `duedate` is '`today+5`' and '`today-5`' . Then I set the 'alert' field as 'Approaching Due date' & 'Over Due' . The flagging mechanism works fine during run time , but the 'alert' column is not showing 'Approaching Due date' & 'Over Due'  in Column header Filter . It just shows Empty .

However if i edit the 'alert' field and enter a text via add new item , it shows up in the filter.

Can anyone please help me with this ?

Answer (score 0):

The function used for filtering gets its options directly from the list and doesn't care about `xsl` on the page, so you're not going to get an easy solution for this. If you're handy with JavaScript and JQuery you could conceivably write your own filter or integrate someone else's.

You could write a workflow or two that pause until date (`duedate-5` and then `duedate+5`) and modify the alert field (this won't work if your duedates change regularly; in that case you'd need to have a daily workflow started by a timer job). Or you could create multiple data views, one with filters to show only items whose duedate is + or - 5 days from today, and another to show only items whose duedates are more than 5 days before today.